# Firefox not rendering contents of a Update panel

Tags: firefox, updatepanel

Why does the following code perform a partial render in IE but not in FF?

In FF, the time on the outside of the updatepanel will also refresh, not so in IE.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <%=DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %>
    </div>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <p>New time is <%=DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %></p> 

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Go get it" />
        </ContentTemplate>

        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </form>
```

Comment: AsyncPostBackTrigger requires EventName="click"

Comment: This does not fix the issue :(

Comment: Do you get any errors in the FF error console?

Comment: No none at all, the code you see above is exaclty what i have, no server side code even

Comment: You are not using any add-ins like NoScript or disabled javascript in Options -> Content tab in FF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I know what version of Firefox you are using?
I tested this on Firefox 3.0 and Firefox 3.5 (clean install - no addons).

If I click the button only the new time refreshes, the outer time *doesn't*. So the partial rendering works.

If you are on Firefox 3.0 or 3.5 can you create a new [firefox profile](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles) to test this?.

Comment: Creating a new profile fixed it. Must be an extension i have installed

Answer (score 0):

Oleg's comment about the EventName attribute on the AsyncPostBackTrigger is likely correct. However, I would add that the Triggers do not need to be explicitly defined in this case since the Button is contained in the UpdatePanel. Events from contained elements trigger the Async Postback by default so it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You've got javascript disabled in FF and it's performing a full postback. :-)